# Orthogonal projection properties.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n \ge 2$ and $a \in R^n-\{0\}$. How can I find the proper subspace $\ker(\lambda I_n-P_a)$ with $P_a$ the orthogonal projection (operator) and What is the dimension of this subspace.

Finally prove that $P_a$ has  exactly two eigenvalues.

Well for this I saw that $$\operatorname{im}(P_a)=\ker(Q_a)=\ker(I_n-P_a) $$ and $$\ker(P_a)=\operatorname{im}(Q_a) $$ but for me it is not clear how find these two eigenvalues.

Some help please. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What is $P_a{}$?

Comment: is the orthogonal projection and $Q_a$ the complementary projection, i.e, $Q_a=I_n-P_a$

Comment: Orthogonal projection onto what?

Comment: Is just the operator, $P_a= \frac{1}{||a||^2}(aa^T)$

Comment: you should include that in the question

Comment: Now, what is $\lambda$?

Comment: An eigenvalue...... There are only two but I do not know how to find them

Comment: So you are asking for the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of $P_a$. Hint: What is $P_a a$?

Comment: Yes I want to find that subspace and the dimension, and $P_a(a)=a$

Comment: what does that mean in context of eigenvalues?

Comment: I do not Know hehhee

Comment: you should lookup the definition of eigenvalue.